# How to read data (int32 , int16 or single byte) from ByteData in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

How to Read data from ByteData.

Here getting response in br (Here br data is ByteArray)
 i want to get following values.

```
ByteData bd = new Int8List.fromList(br).buffer.asByteData();
var firstvalue= bd.getInt32();  //here i am facing issue
var secondvalue= bd.getInt16();
```

Comment: "//here i am facing issue" what issue?

Comment: getting compile time error.                                                                                  var firstvalue= bd.getInt32(8); here it is expecting position  but i dont need to pass position . in ByteData i need to read byte by byte.